# Python Request with Tkinker Variable

Tags: python, tkinter, python-requests

How can I do a `response = requests.get()` with variable from tkinter, like this
so that I can send some bumbersto an api like 20 21 22 and the request looks like
"https://google.com/202122"

```py
def d():
  response = requests.get("myserverip/send.php?host=e2<eq>#%s#&port=e2<eq>#%s#&time=e3<eq>#%s#&method=udp") % (e1, e2, e3)
  print(response)

#call
def d1():
   threading.Thread(target=d).start()

def window():
  window = Tk()
  window.title("tools")
  window.geometry("530x240")
  Label(window, text="1").grid(row=0)
  Label(window, text="2").grid(row=1)
  Label(window, text="3").grid(row=2)
  
  e1 = Entry(window)
  e2 = Entry(window)
  e3 = Entry(window)
  
  e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
  e2.grid(row=1, column=1)
  e3.grid(row=2, column=1)

  Button(window, text='DOREQUEST', bg="gray", fg="white", command=d1).grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=E, pady=30)
       
  frame_label.place(x=210, y=0)                      

  window.mainloop()

#THREADING
p = Process(target=window)
p.start()
p.join()
```

Comment: that sounds like simple `string formatting` ([`f strings`](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/)), so where exactly is the issue?

Comment: the problem is that i dont know how to use f string, but thanks i will look at it
like this? because than it says its not defined but i defined it in tkinter text field
"""
response = requests.post(f"myserverip/send.php?host={e1}&port={e2}&time={e3}&method=udp")
"""

Comment: `response = requests.get("...") % (e1, e2, e3)` should be `response = requests.get("..." % (e1.get(), e2.get(), e3.get()))`.  Also you need to add `global e1, e2, e3` inside `window()`.

Comment: ok so the url look like this? because now it says TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting:
response = requests.post(f"myserverip/send.php?host="% (e1.get(), "&port="% e2.get(), "&time="% e3.get(), "&method=udp"))

Comment: Look carefully, my suggestion is not using `f-string`.

Comment: i what should i use because f string doesnt work i cant get the variable into the url

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: Since you have used `f-string`, so you don't need the part `.format(a,b,c)` and it can be removed.  Also you don't need to use `Process()` to run `window()`, just execute `window()` directly.

Comment: quamrana there wasnt a error thie string wasnt right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
def d():
  a = e1.get()
  b = e2.get()
  c = e3.get()
  print(a, b, c)
  request = requests.get(f"http://google.com/{a}{b}{c}".format(a, b, c))
  print(request)

#call
def d1():
   threading.Thread(target=d).start()

def window():
  window = Tk()
  window.title("tools")
  window.geometry("530x240")
  Label(window, text="1").grid(row=0)
  Label(window, text="2").grid(row=1)
  Label(window, text="3").grid(row=2)
  
  global e1, e2, e3

  e1 = Entry(window)
  e2 = Entry(window)
  e3 = Entry(window)
  
  e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
  e2.grid(row=1, column=1)
  e3.grid(row=2, column=1)

  Button(window, text='DOREQUEST', bg="gray", fg="white", command=d1).grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=E, pady=30)
       
  frame_label.place(x=210, y=0)                      

  window.mainloop()

#THREADING
p = Process(target=window)
p.start()
p.join()
```